# Django and reverse relations from foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

suppose the following simple models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_set')
```

How can I get all the authors that participated in a particular blog (i.e. pk=1)? I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
User.objects.author_set.filter(blog=Blog.objects.get(pk=1))
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have class author as well or no?

Comment: No, why does this matter? The author model is the default User model.

Comment: You also may reconsider the name of your `related_name`. The related name is what will be on your User objects, mapping to the entry set. Something like `related_name='entries'` would make much more sense. That way each User object would have an entries queryset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
User.objects.filter(author_set__blog__pk=1)
```

I wasn't paying attention to your related name, so the code above (revised) now uses the proper related name. However, this is a *really* bad related name. The related name should describe what's on the opposite side, i.e. `Entry`. So really it should be `related_name='entry_set'`. However, that's the default anyways, so you can remove `related_name` if you just want that. I would typically use a simple pluralized version of the related class, which would be in this case `related_name='entries'`. Or, you might want to use something like "blog_entries" to be more specific.

Comment: i just noticed User.objects.filter(author_set__pk=1) is available. Will this give me the same result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. That will return `User`s that are authors of the `Entry` with pk=1. However, I just realized from your comment that my code is not quite right. See update.